# 15 Distinct Weights' Sorting

Tags: combinatorics, weighing

There are $15$ balls. Each of them has a different weight.
You want to sort them according to their weights.
You have a friend who will help you with his scale to do this.
At each weighing process, you will give $3$ balls to him. Then he will specify the order of weights of these $3$ balls. But, he will not say the weights of the balls. (for example: For three balls, he will say only order: $a \gt b \gt c$ )

**At least how many weighing are needed to ensure that all the balls are correctly ordered by their weights**?

Comment: Can we ask your friend to weigh in group, like (a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i) resulting (a,b,c) > (d,e,f) > (g,h,i) ?

Comment: @JamalSenjaya No, by how the puzzle is stated and by how everybody understood it.

Comment: I am not sure to understand well (English is not my native language): can you confirm that "at least" means "minimum" ? So if we are lucky, what is the minimum weighing count? I ask, because I do not see really an answer about that. Am I wrong?

Comment: @lemon: there is also the phrase "to ensure", so the question is asking "What is the minimum number of weightings such that for all cases, you can  always find the order of the 15 balls?"

Answer (score 11):

I can do it in

> 22 weighings.

Step 1:  use 5 weighings, each with 3 new balls, yielding 5 "stacks" that are sorted (imagine the balls stack like coins).

Step 2: Make a state diagram covering all the cases where we have 5 sorted stacks (if two or more apply, pick the earliest):

- A: We know the order of the top coins in 3 of the stacks.  For example, $a > b > c$.
- B: We know the order of disjoint two pairs.  For example, $b > c$ and $d > e$.
- C: We know one coin is heavier than two others.  For example, $d > e$ and $d > a$.
- X: We know less than any of the above.

We start in state X.  Actions to take depending on state:

- A: Weigh $a, d, e$.  This is guaranteed to identify a new heaviest coin.  Set it aside. If the heaviest coin is $a$, then we are now in state B.  Otherwise, we remain in state A.
- B: Weigh $a, b, d$.  This is guaranteed to identify a new heaviest coin. Set it aside.  If the coin $a$ is heaviest, we remain in state B.  If $a$ is middle, we move to state A.  If coin $a$ is lightest, we move to state C.
- C: Weigh $d,b, c$.  This is guaranteed to identify a heaviest coin.  Set it aside.  If $d$ is heaviest, we end up in state X.  If $d$ is middle, we are in state C.  If lightest, we end up in state B.
- X: Weigh $a,b, c$.  We do not identify a heaviest coin, but are guaranteed to end in state A.

The only way to return to state X is by passing through A to B to C to X.
Thus, starting in state X, we can guarantee to identify the next three heaviest coins in at most four weighings.  Repeat this four times to use 16 weighings to identify the 12 heaviest coins, leaving 3 left.  One more weighing will identify the order of those 3.

> So we have 5 weighings in step 1 and at most 17 weighings in step 2, for a total of 22 weighings.  Best case is when we never return to state X, for a total of 19 weighings.

Comment: I really like this approach, and this was a well written and easy to follow example. I think the result is correct, but the state diagram does not encompass all possibilities. For example, 
X => _a_ > _b_ > _c_*|* 
A => *a* > _d_ > _e_*|*
 B => *a* > _b_ > _d_*|*
 B => *a* > _b_ > _d_. Now stack _a_ has been exhausted. We could continue with Action B until, without loss of generality, stack _c_ is also exhausted. Your state diagram would have us stick with action B, however we no longer know _b_ > ?? and _d_ > _e_ since _c_ is gone. It is (I think) possible to get back to X not through C

Comment: My heart is convinced that you are correct, and I think it will be a minor tweak to make the state diagram cover cases where there are 4 or 3 stacks remaining (3 stacks will always generate a new heaviest coin).
I also think you can improve your best case (I know it wasn't in OP question). If 2 piles are exhausted immediately (7 weighings), and you then exhaust a 3rd pile with 3 weighings, you can write a state diagram for the 2 stack case such that if _a1_ > _a2_ > _b1, you take 2 off _a1_ at once. This can get 4 coins off with 2 weighings. 1 more wieghing finishes it. 13 weighings best case

Comment: I think the best case is far less than 19 weighings.

Comment: Good points. I didn't deal with tweaks to improve best case; I was focused on worst case, and proving 22 was enough.  Stack exhaustion only makes things easier.  I think best case would be 16: 7 to remove the first ball, 5 more to eliminate a total of two stacks, 3 to eliminate six more, and 1 for the last three.

Comment: I imagine there's an algorithm with a faster worst case.  My first 6 checks are ideal: each divides the solution space by a factor of 6.  But my 7th check is far less efficient.  But a faster algorithm might have to be terribly complex.

Comment: Do you think alternating approaching the stacks from the top and bottom would be better? Whenever you might otherwise have to make a sub-optimal check (dividing the solution space by a factor less than 6), alternate which side you're working from? I'm not sure how you identified the 7th check as sub-optimal, but this would buy you a couple more optimal moves I think (repeat action X and A on the bottom should divide by factor of 6 twice more). Or is another completely different approach required?

Comment: @TonyEnnis It may be less, but not *far* less.  You are trying to infer information about 15 coins relative to each other.  Not an easy problem to solve.

Comment: I believe that in case C, d lightest, you can go to A rather than to B...

Comment: Wow! I implemented this in Sage (Python moreorless), after some troubleshooting of empty piles I got it working, and this is an amazing thing! Btw, the worst case happens for instance for the following initial weights in the groups: $[6, 3, 11], [13, 10, 2], [8, 14, 4], [1, 12, 9], [5, 15, 7]$. I would be really surprised if someone managed to be much faster than this for the worst case.

Comment: @user1540815 The problem is that you have to reorder the stacks between some steps. Also, the problem is trivial on 4 stacks as long as you know the comparison of two arbitrary stacks, because with 1 measurement, you get the highest value and you know the comparison of two stacks. I'm also sure that this can't be trivially reduced from 22 because you can end with 5 stacks with 1 coin each and in state X, and then you know nothing and need 4 comparisons no matter what.

Answer (score 10):

> 25 is an upper bound on the number of weighings you need.

Lemma: 
Fully ordering a pile of 5 stones takes 4 weighings (this is easy to prove but I can do so if necessary).

Fully ordering a pile of 5 stones can be done as follows:

a.) Assign each stone a number.

b.) Weigh stones 1, 2, and 3. Based on the results, renumber the stones so that 1 is the lightest, 2 is second, and 3 is the heaviest of the 3.

c.) Using the new numbers, weigh stones 3, 4, and 5. Based on the results, renumber them if necessary. If stone 3 remained stone 3, you are now done (2 weighings total). If not, stone 5 is at least guaranteed to be the heaviest stone overall.

d.) Again using the new numbers, weigh stones 2, 3, 4 and renumber if necessary. if no reordering was necessary, you are now done (3 weighings total). If not, stone 4 is at least guaranteed to be the second heaviest stone overall.

e.) Now that stones 4 and 5 are in the right place, weigh (using the new numbers) stones 1, 2, and 3 again. Renumber them based on the result, and now all 5 stones are guaranteed to be ordered correctly.

Details:

1.) Split the input stones into 3 piles of 5 stones (No weighings required)

2.) Order each of the 3 piles

> (2-4 weighings each, 6-12 total weighings are required)

3.) While there are stones left in each pile (and more than 3 stones left total), weigh the heaviest stone from each pile. Put the heaviest one in the next available spot in the output area. This step will be repeated 12 times (then only 3 stones are left).

3.a) If you are lucky, all of the first 5 heaviest stones will come from the same sub pile (5 weighings done). The 6th heaviest stone is also now clear. You can now compare the 2 heaviest stones from the shorter pile with the single heaviest from the other pile. If you continue to be lucky, the 2 heaviest stones are both heavier than the heaviest from the other pile. Then you can put both into the output area at once. In this way, you can go from piles of 4-5 to 2-5 to 0-5, at which point you need no further weighings. This can skip step 4.

> (7-12 weighings total)

4.) Weigh the last 3 stones, and put them in the correct order.

> (1 weighing)

.

> In the worst case this strategy requires 25 weighings. If you are given completely sorted input (or randomly generate the piles very luckily) step 2 will only take 6 weighings and step 3 will only take 7. Best case is 13 weighings, worst case is 25 under this strategy.

Comment: I believe this method has a range of 16-25 weighings required. Step 2, with good fortune, can be done in 9, and Step 3 in 12. Excellent algorithm.

Comment: I arrived at the same totals you did: 16-25 weightings required. However, I believe you meant to say Step 2, with good fortune, can be done in 6. With the specific method I outlined in my edit, the "good fortune" case actually corresponds to sorted input, so this method should perform better the closer to sorted the input already was.

Comment: @user1540815 It is a good adhoc approach, kudos :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In step 3, by "no more than 3 stones left" do you mean "more than 3 stones left"? And please could you clarify "the 3 heaviest stones from each pile"? Which 3 stones, exactly?

Comment: Wow, I typo'd my comment pretty horribly, my initial thought was 9/7 split between steps 2 and 3, skipping step 4. You've shown me a 6/7 split, which I've suggested an edit to add to your answer. 13-25 is pretty good, considering the absolute minimum best case is 7.

Comment: @RosieF you are correct. edited to "more that 3 stones left". Also I meant "take the heaviest stone from each pile and weigh those 3 stones together"

Comment: What is the worst case scenario?

Comment: Nice answer.  A little inefficient though since you are weighing the heaviest three in each pile possibly repeatedly.  For example, if pile 1 is abc, pile 2 is def, and pile 3 is ghi, then you would weigh adg and say a is heaviest.  Then you'd weigh bdg.  But you already know d<g so why include it?  A better choice might be bcd.

Comment: @Trenin you are correct. I'm sure this improves the best case (you can exhaust the first pile in 3 weighings instead of 5), and I'll later try to analyze more rigorously how this affects the worst case. Wonderful suggestion!

Answer (score 5):

It should be at least (the strict lower bound) :

> $\lceil \log_6(15!)\rceil$ = $16$

Its reasoning:

> Total possible orderings are: $15!$ i.e. factorial(15)
>  At least $\log_6(15!)$ is [needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) because at a time three weights are used and out of 6 possibilities, one is output.
>
>  
>
>  Using [the Quick sort (the median of three pivot) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) (I might be completely wrong in using this algorithm, 3 partition merge sort with an ad-hoc merge function would be better). Each call to the ordering(weighing) function gives you one ordering(a tuple of 3 weights).
>
>  So, after running on Ideone, [$28$ is output](http://ideone.com/yKtQoe).

---

The actual answer showing optimal comparisons needs a better algorithm.

Comment: My answer (I believe) hits that lower bound! Would you mind giving it a quick look to see if there are any obvious errors?

Comment: Why are you using 3 as the base of the logarithm? There are *6* possible outcomes of each 3-ball weighing operation, so the base of the logarithm should be 6. (As an example of why the base isn't the number of balls involved in a weighing, consider how many operations it takes to sort 15 balls with a 15-ball weighing operation.)

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing that out, am probably too tired to think...

Comment: I am pretty sure the lower bound is 7, given the balls are selected in exactly the right order.

Comment: @TonyEnnis See, if the balls are chosen in perfect order i.e. each new ball is lightest than the previous two balls(other than the heaviest), then 13 weighings would be required. 7 would be if you take only one lightest ball from the previous weighing. But the problem with these is that we need the solution which works for every input case of 15! possibilities.

Comment: I don't see how that is correct. See my answer below.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Well, the answer is a lower bound for the worst case, not for the best case. Of course, the best case is 7 because you can verify they are ordered in 7 steps: $1<2<3$, $3<4<5$, $5<6<7$, $7<8<9$, $9<10<11$, $11<12<13$, $13<14<15$. But that's not the interesting side.

Comment: @ABcDexter You should IMHO take the ceil, not the floor, i.e., it shall be 16.

Comment: @yo' I'll check into that, and I do feel the same. It's just the lack of sleep and running nose which cause uneven logical thinking.

Comment: Well, simply put: you can't sort 2 balls in $\lfloor\log_6(2!)\rfloor=0$ measurements ;-) The rule says that the information obtained from $n$ measurements is surely (non-strictly) less than $n\,\mathrm{sit}$ ($1\,\mathrm{sit} = \log_2 6\,\mathrm{bit}$), i.e., $n\geq \log_6 15!$.

Answer (score 4):

I found a an interesting article about that [15 balls article](http://www.diophante.fr/images/stories/diophante/juin_2018_01/A727-Ordering_15_marbles_with_a_three-way_scale.pdf). Acording to this source,

> we need a 20 weightings to sort the 15 balls.

---

They are unable to proove it is the minimum possible number. But they say 16 is a proven lower bound. I won't within the details of all demonstation but just show the main results and the final demonstration.

Firstly they proove the minimum weighting for number of balls up to 9.

> 3 weighings suffice to sort 4 marbles.
>  4 weighings suffice to sort 5 marbles.
>  5 weighings suffice to sort 6 marbles.
>  6 weighings suffice to sort 7 marbles.
>  8 weighings suffice to sort 8 marbles.
>  9 weighings suffice to sort 9 marbles.

---

Then, they go on the 15 balls problem with this set of intermediate demonstation

> Lemma1: 4 weighings suffice to sort six marbles containing two disjoint chains of length 2.
>  Lemma2: 5 weighings suffice to sort seven marbles containing three disjoint chains of length 2.
>  Lemma3: 13 weighings suffice to sort 15 marbles ordered as presented there:
>  [image: 15 marbles]
>  Lemma4: 6 weighings suffice to sort eight marbles ordered as presented there:
>  [image: 8 marbles]
>  Lemma5: 12 weighings suffice to sort 15 marbles as presented there:
>  [image: 15 marbles]

---

**Final proof using all theorems:**

> 20 weighings suffice to sort 15 marbles.

Partition the 15 marbles into five groups of three, and weigh them.
Use a sixth weighing to compare the middle marbles of three groups, and let
a denote the middle one. The following graph illustrates the situation.
[image]
Use a seventh weighing to compare `a`,`b` and `c`. Without any loss in
generality, assume that `b` is heavier than `c` . Three cases need to be
considered.

*Case 1*: `a` is the middle marble of the seventh weighing.
The marble `b` is heavier than `a` , and `c` is lighter than `a` . The situation is exactly that of Lemma3, and therefore 13 additional weighings suffice for a total of xx.
[image]

*Case 2*: `a` is the heaviest marble of the seventh weighing.
With an eighth weighing, compare the three shaded marbles. Since
these three marbles are lighter than `a` , the resulting graph is exactly that of Lemma 5, and 12 additional weighings suffice, for a grand total of xx.
[image]

*Case 3*:  `a` is the lightest marble.
The situation is isomorphic to the previous one, where the roles of heaviest and lightest are reversed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is

> 55

because

> Arbitrarily choose the first three balls and determine their weights. This operation costs one weight, and we now know where they are in comparison to each other. For the sake of example, call them A, B, and C such that A < B < C. Now we introduce a fourth ball, D. Compare D with A and B. If it is the smaller than or in between A and B, we know its exact location. If not, we must compare it with C to see if it is smaller or larger. This costs two additional operations. Say we now have A < B < C < D. When introducing E, following the same process will yield another two operations (compare to A and B, if that doesn't help, then compare to C and D). Introduce a new ball, follow the same process, this will now cost us three operations. The patterns of required operations to determine the new ball's location is as follows: 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, etc. This yields:
>  1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 4 + 5 + 5 + 6 + 6 + 7 + 7 = 55 for 15 balls.

Comment: I think this is the strict upper bound. (forming *k*-combinations from set of 15 unlabeled elements, with k=2.)

Comment: Yes, if using this strategy, this is the maximum number of operations we would need to do, which would also be the minimum to ensure that we'll be able to order everything correctly. That being said, my answer anyway got beaten out by everyone else :)

Comment: I think the upper bound is far less than 55.

Answer (score 1):

My answer do not give exact numbers of weighting, but nice algorithm to attack the problem.

> Take a ball as pivot, like A, than, weight all remaining ball with A.
>  You will get a group of 3 [balls lighter than A] , [A] , [balls heavier than A].

than

> Now from balls lighter than A do the same algorithm.
>  Also do the same algorithm with balls heavier than A.

Comment: This is known as [Quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) with worst case complexity O($N^2$)